# Error when adding objects into a collection after deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, collections

I cant figure out what's wrong  with my program. There are 3 classes, `Owner` is singleton, so when `GUI` request for `Owner` instance, the `getOwner()` method in `Owner` returns previously saved `Owner`, otherwise returns new `Owner`. I think serialization is implemented correctly. `Map` `cars` collection is transient, no need to save when exit.

When program runs for the first time the user by pressing either button in gui can execute `intoMap1()` or `intoMap2()` method in which `Owner` is asked in its `addCar()` method to create car and insert into its `Map`collection with key `A1` or/and `B2`. I checked that `Map` `cars` contains 1 or 2 cars after each program run, so no problems yet.

When program is closed and opened again, the `Owner` was saved  and deserialized in  `Cars.ser` file with no errors, I checked that with print statements. The problem is when program is run again the `addCar()` in `Owner` it creates the new car but doesnt add it to `cars` `Map`, it causes exception. The Map `cars` was not saved so its empty and anyway even if in the first run I insert into map car `A1`, it wouldnt insert new car `B2` in the second run. Is there anything wrong with `Map` being transient? Why it doesn't add cars to map in the second run? If I remove `Cars.ser` file it again add cars in the first run. It seems that at the second run the `Map` doesnt want to cooperate. In second run new object is created with previously saved field `name;`. Is the hashing causing problems?

Exceptions are caused only in the second run in `Owner` Line 34, and  `cars.containsKey(regNumIn)` fails for some reason  at Line 45.

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    Owner owne;

    public GUI()
    {   
        owne = Owner.getOwner();  //name is correctly retrieved each time                            
        System.out.println(owne.toString());  //name is printed each time                        
        addWindowListener(new CloseQuit());        
        initComponents();
    }

    public void intoMap1()  //executed by pressing button in gui, asking owne object to create and add car
    {
        owne.addCar("A1", "red", 6); //Line 36    
    }

    public void intoMap2()  //executed by pressing button in gui, asking owne object to add cars  
    {
41      owne.addCar("B2", "black", 4); //Line 41    
    }

    private class CloseQuit extends WindowAdapter  
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println("CloseQuit executed");
            owne.saveOwner();
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
public class Owner implements Serializable
{
    String name;    
    transient Map<String, Car> cars;

    public Owner()
    {
        name = "John";
        cars = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addCar(String regNumIn, String colourIn, int doorsIn)
    {
        Car car = new Car(regNumIn, colourIn, doorsIn); //works in each execution 
        System.out.println("Car is created" + car.toString());              
         try
         {
34           cars.put(regNumIn, car);  //Line 34, works only when program runs first time, 
                                       //after Owner is deserialized it doesnt add cars with new keys, exception
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             System.out.println("Exception in Owner when adding car "); 
             ex.printStackTrace();   
         }

        try
        {        
45          System.out.println("Map has key " + regNumIn  + ":  " + cars.containsKey(regNumIn)); //Line 45
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    public static Owner getOwner()  //works fine
    {
        Owner owne = null;
        try
        {                                        
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Cars.ser");                                                                    
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);                                                                          
            owne = (Owner) ois.readObject(); ois.close();       
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            owne = new Owner(); //creates new Owner if run for first time  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
       {                
           System.exit(0);
       }            
       return owne;
   }

   public void saveOwner()  //works fine 
   {
       try
       {
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("Cars.ser"); 
            ObjectOutputStream ois = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
            ois.writeObject(this); ois.close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           System.out.println("Can't store state of owner");  
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return ("name = " + name);
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Car 
{
    String regNum;
    String colour;
    int doors;

    public Car(String regNumIn, String colourIn, int doorsIn)
    {
        regNum = regNumIn;
        colour = colourIn;
        doors = doorsIn;
    }    

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("regNum = " + regNum );
    }
}
```

After first run ouput is:

```
run:
--------------
name = John
--------------
Car is created: regNum = A1
Map has key A1:  true
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Car is created: regNum = B2
Map has key B2:  true
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CloseQuit executed
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

After second run output is:

```
   run:
--------------
name = John
--------------
Car is created: regNum = A1
Exception in Owner when adding car
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.Owner.addCar(Owner.java:34)
    at gui.GUI.intoMap1(GUI.java:36)
    at gui.GUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(GUI.java:215)
    at gui.GUI.access$100(GUI.java:17)
    at gui.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:87)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.Owner.addCar(Owner.java:45)
    at gui.GUI.intoMap1(GUI.java:36)
    at gui.GUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(GUI.java:215)
    at gui.GUI.access$100(GUI.java:17)
    at gui.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:87)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Car is created: regNum = B2
Exception in Owner when adding car
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.Owner.addCar(Owner.java:34)
    at gui.GUI.intoMap2(GUI.java:41)
    at gui.GUI.jButton4ActionPerformed(GUI.java:230)
    at gui.GUI.access$400(GUI.java:17)
    at gui.GUI$4.actionPerformed(GUI.java:126)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.Owner.addCar(Owner.java:45)
    at gui.GUI.intoMap2(GUI.java:41)
    at gui.GUI.jButton4ActionPerformed(GUI.java:230)
    at gui.GUI.access$400(GUI.java:17)
    at gui.GUI$4.actionPerformed(GUI.java:126)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
CloseQuit executed
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the code for the `Owner` class, as well as the *entire* stack trace of the exception.

Comment: There is already full code for Owner class, and  there is no stack trace in the output, all exceptions are caught.

Comment: I see the class now.  When you catch an exception, *always* print or log its full stack trace, with something like `ex.printStackTrace();`.  The exception tells you (and us) what is going wrong, and why.  Without that information, we can only guess what’s wrong.

Comment: Now the code is more readable, at each user button press, only one car should be added at a time.

Comment: Do you know what `transient` does?  Try removing that word, and making the `Car` class serializable.

Comment: I did that, and it works now. I think the exception was caused because ‘cars' collection declared transient, after first run the collection was not saved and during deserialization of 'Owner' in the second run, the default constructor where new 'HasMap'  'cars' collection should be initialized was not called. Thus, in the second run ‘car’ object was attempted to be added to non existing ‘cars' collection.

Comment: Correct.  `transient` means a field will not be saved during serialization.  So when you deserialize the data, a transient field is always null/zero/false.  There are ways to compensate for it, but in your case it’s easier to just avoid using `transient` at all.